# Trying to read a pdf file in modal popup on button click

Tags: c#, html, css, razor

In my project the client should able to see the syllabus for a particular subject in modal popup on click on the subject name. The pdf file is in the folder called PDF in my project MVCApplication1.

Here is the code I have tried:

```
@{  
string path = "~/PDF/SIMS.pdf";
string b = HttpContext.Current.Request.MapPath(path);
}
@try
{
if (File.Exists(b))
{
<embed src=@path width="900" height="400"/>
}
else
{
<marquee>NOT SET</marquee>
}
}
catch(Exception e)
{
Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
}
```

This is not working for me.
But if the change the src in `<embed>` from @path to "~/PDF/SIMS.pdf" then it is working.

Is this the right way to do this, or is there any other way for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`path` is a C# variable which holds a string value. So when you set the `src` property value, you need to wrap it with double quotes.

```
<embed src="@path" width="900" height="400"/>
```

But you cannot directly use `"~/PDF/SIMS.pdf"` as the source. You may use `Url.Content` helper method to get the proper relative path to your file.

```
<embed src="@Url.Content(path)" width="900" height="400"/>
```

Comment: Check the view source and see whether you are getting the correct path value.

Comment: it is showing right path i.e, `src="~/PDF/SIMS.pdf"` but, if i click on that link it's giving this Error - 404.0 - Not Found

Comment: Can you try to access the path in a browser ? If no, then your path is wrong !

Comment: but brother if i won't use the variable path and gives the direct path `src="~/PDF/SIMS.pdf"` then it is working.

Comment: When you use the variable and checking the rendered markup , Are you seeing a different value ?

Comment: Take a look at my updated answer. You need to use Url.Content method. As long as you have a file exists in `~/PDF` with name `SIMS.pdf`, It will work.